# Configure VSCode to build only when file is edited

Tags: settings, visual-studio-code

VSCode re-builds my C++ programs every time I try to debug or run it, even if there is no change in the program. This is, at the very least, time-consuming.

Is there a setting to build the program only if the file was changed?

Comment: No use a build tool like Make, CMake,....

Comment: or define 2 launch configs, one with a build task, one without build task